# #1054 - Unknown column - backticks issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, mariadb

Basically, I have this query:

```
SELECT *, `groups`.`goodname`
FROM students AS s
INNER JOIN groups AS g
        ON s.univ_group = g.id
WHERE name LIKE "%А%"
```

And it gives this error on query attempt: `#1054 - Unknown column 'groups.goodname' in 'field list'`

Already tried `'groups'.goodname, 'groups.goodname', goodname.'groups', goodname.groups` (**'** stands for **`** here due to SO markup reasons) and so on. I know that it's related to these backticks but I can not figure out how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Querying in PMA, using MariaDB server of latest version. And yeah I'm completely sure that this column exists :)

Comment: Is there any need of column when u r already using *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have added the alias to 'groups' table - 'g', the query is not recognizing the table with `groups` name anymore, you need to use alias name, so you need to change 
`groups`.`goodname` to g.`goodname`

```
SELECT *, g.`goodname`
FROM students AS s
INNER JOIN groups AS g
        ON s.univ_group = g.id
WHERE name LIKE "%А%"
```

Comment: actually no. But if you want to get some field with exact or specific name, you can do it.
 For example 
SELECT *, g.`goodname` AS good_name

Comment: Yes agreed with yur example

Comment: If it helped you, accept it as an answer, to help the other users, when they have a problem like that.

Comment: Actually I am not the OP :p

Comment: Does `*` still work when you also specify explicit columns in the `SELECT` list?  I don't think so... you'd need to `SELECT s.*, g.*, g.goodname` although with `SELECT *` there's not a lot of point in selecting the column a second time.

Comment: `*` is a synonym for `s.*, g.*` in _that_ example.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot In this query `*` is returning all columns from students and groups tables + g.goodname, So there will be 2 columns with `goodname` name. And YES - it will work, you can try it yourself.
Also I agree ,In this case it is unnecessary to use `*` +   g.`goodname`. 
It will be ok when you want to get that field with specific name. Then you will query also g.`goodname` but in this case with alias .
SELECT *, g.goodname AS good_name

Comment: Yes, I understand quite clearly what it is supposed to be, but I don't believe the parser in MySQL understands it when explicit columns are also requested. I'll verify.

Comment: You can try it, I have tried and make lot of that kind of queries, I know what I am talking about ;)